# Why does no one on earth use the fixed file info file date?

Tags: windows, winapi, exe, fileinfo, binaries

Finalizing the version information written in a Windows [binary exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format), I found out that [the field FileDate in FIXEDFILEINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/verrsrc/ns-verrsrc-vs_fixedfileinfo) in [file resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-file-formats) is always set up as 0. This FileDate field is given in [FILETIME format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime). At first I thought it strictly means the creation date and time stamp of the files generated is Jan 1 1601 : `File Date = 00:00:00  01/01/1601`. But then, I found out that in many Microsoft date formats, the date number as 0 means the date is not valid, or not meaningful, or unspecified. Still, I haven't found clear info about the 0 meaning here.

I seek for files which haven't set it as 0 and I can't find any single one. All code sample on StackOverflow give 0 ([Python there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325106/12457285)) or not specify this field ([C++ there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37285135/12457285)). Even the Windows system32 binaries use 0. So why no one is filling up this data with correct date ? Is there any guideline telling this can be let as 0 ? And what would be the benefit of a non-zero value there ?

Comment: Having a hard time understanding, what this question is really asking for. What problem do you need to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your time. The question is : why the Windows exe resource FileDate fields in FIXEDFILEINFO (also described as Fixed File Info : File Date, or in the Win32 API documentation : the DWORD pair dwFileDateMS and dwFileDateLS) is ever ever set to 0, at least in all the the exe files I've examinated ? And what's the rational of setting this field to 0 ?
There is no real problem about this, just a personal interrogation to know why everyone sets this as 0, and not as the actual exe building time (as it should, to me).

Comment: There already exists [TimeDateStamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_file_header) in the PE header, maybe that's why this one isn't used.

Comment: Historically, it's more likely, that the version information isn't used, because the filesystem (both FAT32 and NTFS) already store a creation timestamp. The timestamp in the PE header [has been repurposed in Windows 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705), giving reason to believe, that Windows doesn't care much about the creation time of modules. If you are deploying software and have a reason to encode the creation time, feel free to populate the version information.